# Generating stub java code for web service communication with AXIS ADB - how to exclude the 'local' variable name prefix?

Tags: apache-axis, webservice-client

I'm trying to generate stub java code for communicate web service by using axis adb (databind)

command for build stub..

call wsdl2java -p com.microsofttranslator.api.v2.languageService -d adb -s -u -uri
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc?wsdl

But generated stub java codes model has local variable name (prefix variable name)
`/**
* field for AppId
*/

```
                                protected java.lang.String localAppId ;
                            
                       /*  This tracker boolean wil be used to detect whether the user called the set method
                      *   for this attribute. It will be used to determine whether to include this field
                       *   in the serialized XML
                       */
                       protected boolean localAppIdTracker = false ;
                       

                       /**
                       * Auto generated getter method
                       * @return java.lang.String
                       */
                       public  java.lang.String getAppId(){
                           return localAppId;
                       }`
```

ref: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/reference.html

call wsdl2java -p com.microsofttranslator.api.v2.languageService -d adb -s -u -uri
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc?wsdl

-E databinding.properties

adb.localname.exclude=local?

`localAppId -> appId`

How can I generated class without prefix[local] name like as 'appId' not 'localAppId'?
Please advise. thank you,

ref: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/reference.html

Is there option to generate java classes with variable names that do not include the "local" prefix?